# How to check the symmetry of an integer singly-linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a question about singly-linked list in C++.

An integer array[0..n] is called symmetric if array[0] = array[n], array[1] = array[n-1], ...

For example: 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1

So, is there any way to check the symmetry of an integer singly-linked list?

I've thought about copying the value of them downto an array then check the symmetry of this array but I think it is not good because the featured of link list will be lost.

Comment: how will copying to array will cause link list to get lost?

Comment: It won't lost data, but the featured will.
Because if there is any problem with linked-list you always copy to an array and then do a process to fix problem using array, linked-list is just nothing.

Comment: Of course possible, and just because you generate a data structure for analysis doesn't mean you destroy the original. If you cache the number of elements in the list, you could get a test of when an arbitrarily long singly-linked list of numbers is *not* symmetric in one pass. e.g. do some kind of checksum on the first half and compare to the checksum of the second half. Then you could only pay the cost of the full test if the checksums match. Other tricks like that with caching which may be worth considering--but you'd have to provide context, as the single-link requirement is not explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic way is to fold over the list and push elements on a stack until half way, then pop from the stack and compare with remaining elements.

```
bool isPalindrome(forward_list<int> &l){
 forward_list<int> stack;
 auto it = l.begin();
 int len = 0;
 int i   = 0;
 while (it != l.end()){
   ++len;
   ++it;
 }
 if (len <= 1)
   return true;
 it = l.begin();
 while (i < (len / 2)) {
   stack.push_front(*it);
   ++i;
   ++it;
 }
 if ((len % 2) == 1) 
   ++it;
 while (!stack.empty()){
   if (stack.front() != *it)
     return false;
   stack.pop_front();
   ++it;
 }
 return true;
}

bool test_good(const int i){
 int j = i / 2;
 forward_list<int> l;
 for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
   l.push_front(k); 
 }
 if (i % 2 == 1){
   l.push_front(j);
 }
 for (int k = j-1; k >= 0; k--){
   l.push_front(k);
 }
 return isPalindrome(l);
}

bool test_bad(const int i){
 forward_list<int> l;
 for (int k = 0; k < i; k++){
   l.push_front(k); 
 }
 l.push_front(i);
 l.push_front(i+1);
 return !isPalindrome(l);
}

int main(){
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   cout << "test for " << i << "...";
   if (test_good(i))
     cout << "ok...";
   else return i;
   if (test_bad(i))
     cout << "ok." << endl;
   else return i;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I used a `forward_list` to implement the stack, rather than using the dedicated `std::stack` template.
Also, note that the problem is trickier when using generic lists of `T`, since you don't necessarily want to instantiate copies of values in the list when pushing on the stack, but you can't push references to values of primitive types (like `char` or `int`). For that problem, you would have to provide two different templated implementations, which would be `enable_if`ed according to what `T` is. You would probably also add the comparison operator to the template.

Answer (score 1):

If by "simple-linked" you actually mean *singly* linked, then you *have* to copy half of them - whether on the stack using recursion or to an array.

```
bool is_symmetric(Node* p, int n)
{
    Value values[n / 2]; // use alloca or std::vector if your compiler doesn't support
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i, p = p->next)
         values[i] = p->value;
    if ((n + 1) % 2) p = p->next; // for odd number of elements, middle one's ok
    for (; i >= 0; --i, p = p->next)
         if (values[i] != p->value)
             return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this, and it might have an error or two, but the general idea's there....

If it's doubly linked, it's even easier - iterate half way then iterate in both directions doing the comparisons.

Comment: singly-linked, I edited.
Thank you for answering. It's helpful.